# Start javaw JFrame from BAT appearing behind File Explorer in Windows

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, window

I've had a batch file that for a long time has had no issues and started a JAR using javaw.exe in Windows, which then appears in front of other running Windows applications. Recently the batch file has been changed and I'm now consistently experiencing the JFrame, which is opened by the javaw.exe, to appear behind the File Explorer that was used to open the BAT file.

Specifically it appears on the task bar, blinking, but is not visible on screen because it is hidden behind the File Explorer that spawned it. It is not minimized.

Previously the batch was something along the lines of (somewhat simplified):

```
rem BOM safeguard
@echo off
set APPDIR=%~dp0
fc "%APPDIR%a.txt" "%APPDIR%b.txt" > fc1.txt
start "" "%APPDIR%..\jre\bin\javaw" -jar "%APPDIR%Testorama.jar"
```

Now it is something along the lines of:

```
rem BOM safeguard
@echo off
set APPDIR=%~dp0
fc "%APPDIR%a.txt" "%APPDIR%b.txt" > fc1.txt
fc "%APPDIR%a.txt" "%APPDIR%b.txt" > fc2.txt
xcopy /y "%APPDIR%Testorama.jar" "%APPDIR%Temp"
start "" "%APPDIR%..\jre\bin\javaw" -jar "%APPDIR%Testorama.jar"
```

To exclude the JAR being an issue I've replaced it, and it still occurs. Currently the JAR is a simple main:

```
package testorama;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new TestFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

With the new bat above, I can comment out any of the `fc`-s or the `xcopy` and it will start being in front, but if all three are in there the problem occurs. At this point I have no clue why this inconsistency occurs. If I add a `pause` after the `start` it appears in front, but I do not want the prompt to be left open.

Why is this occuring? What can I do to mitigate the issue while maintaining all commands (as they have clear missions in running our application)?

My environment is a up-to-date Windows 10 and the javaw is JRE8. The problem occurs on other machines with a similar setup, while I haven't tested other OSes or JREs.

Comment: What does happen on appending below last line with `start` the command line `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 >nul` to wait one second before processing of batch file finishes resulting most likely in `cmd.exe` terminates itself?

Comment: @Mofi that does indeed solve the issue! I'll have to try it a bit more, but my first attempts says it works. I also tried `/T 0`, and that did also work. I then tried something random like `echo ".."`, but that did not work. Apparently it might have something to do with the existance of the "parent" (the cmd window) when the frame of the java application launches...? Slightly guessing. Also unclear how that has anything to do with the commands run before `javaw`.

Comment: I guessed also that the Java main window is created, but loses the input focus before being displayed in foreground and Windows lets the symbol of just started GUI app blink in the Windows taskbar to notify the user to take attention on this application. But like you I am wondering also why a short delay of about half a second is necessary after starting `javaw.exe` and why it is only necessary after first running twice `fc.exe` and once `xcopy.exe`. I have no explanation for that. It is perhaps possible to find out with Process Monitor what happens here in the background explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input of @Mofi I ended up "solving" this by doing a minimal `timeout` command after running `javaw`.

My new BAT appearance is now:

```
rem BOM safeguard
@echo off
set APPDIR=%~dp0
fc "%APPDIR%a.txt" "%APPDIR%b.txt" > fc1.txt
fc "%APPDIR%a.txt" "%APPDIR%b.txt" > fc2.txt
xcopy /y "%APPDIR%Testorama.jar" "%APPDIR%Temp"
start "" "%APPDIR%..\jre\bin\javaw" -jar "%APPDIR%Testorama.jar"
timeout /T 0
```

I can only guess that this has to do with the existance of the parent prompt, at the time that `javaw` wants to display the JFrame, or some other obscure timing problem.